# Binary data to file download of any extension in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, blob

I have a binary data saved in MongoDB. How can I covert this binary data into downloadable file of any filetype(.txt,.pdf,.img).

[image: File snapshot in DB]

Using JavaScript blob I tried to generate and download the file as per below code snippet;

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style.display = 'none';
const data = =attachments[0].file.data;
const blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"});
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.href = url;
a.download = name;
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

This doesn't seem to work as it downloads a file with no extension and as [object Object] if I open the file through Notepad. What data should be set as first parameter in the new Blob(data, type) to get the correct file